# Push value into array using $(this) with DRY approach jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry

I am having some trouble finding a way to push into an array based on the div.

My goal is to add up the amount of time that I am hovering over each element.  Instead, of creating the same function for each div.  I wanted to try a **DRY**  approach.   This is difficult to visualize.

I want to change the array I am pushing into when I change the div.  I have figured out a way to add all of the time into one array. However this is not my goal.

Here is a very shortened version of my code and I am attaching a plunker to show how it is working.  In the console you can see the time change.

http://plnkr.co/edit/zBRyix6TJjTjvp7OCrMC?p=preview

I am pushing into the timeArray.  Ideally I could push into panelHeading array or panelHeadingArray

Here is my iffe being used in a  **DRY**  approach.

```
var timeMonitering = (function() {
    var mouseenterTime = 0;
    var timeArray = [];
    var navArray = [];
    var panelHeadingArray = [];

    return {
        inAndOut: inAndOut
    }

    function inAndOut(evt) {
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var mouseoverTime;
        if(evt.type === 'mouseenter') {
            mouseenterTime = currentTime.getTime();
        }
        else if (evt.type === 'mouseleave') {
            mouseoverTime =currentTime.getTime(); 

        }

        var time =mouseoverTime - mouseenterTime;
        if(time >0) {
            timeArray.push(time/1000);
        }
        console.log('time array added',Math.round(timeArray.reduce(add,0) ));
        return time/1000;
    }

    function add(a,b) {
        return a +b;
    }

})();




 $(document).on('ready', function() {
    $('.navbar').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', timeMonitering.inAndOut);

   $('.panel-heading').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', timeMonitering.inAndOut);
});
```

Need to figure out how to push into **navArray or panelHeadingArray** 
depending on where I mouseover.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***********Update ******************

Here is how I essentially was able to add each array's time up.
The jumbotronArray adds the seconds up as I hover over the element.  However, I would like to  reuse this function or like the one I showed above.

```
var enteredTime = 0;
var jumbotronArray = [];
var listGroupArray = [];


$('.jumbotron').hover(function(evt) {
  enteredTime = new Date();
  console.log('e',enteredTime)
}, function() {
  var ctime = new Date();
  var time = (ctime.getTime() - enteredTime.getTime())/1000;

  jumbotronArray.push(time);
  console.log('time spend ' + time/1000 + 'sec');
  console.log('jumbotronArray',jumbotronArray)
  console.log('added',Math.round(jumbotronArray.reduce(add,0) ));
})


$('.list-group').hover(function(evt) {
  enteredTime = new Date();
}, function() {
  var ctime = new Date();
  var time = (ctime.getTime() - enteredTime.getTime())/1000;

  listGroupArray.push(time);
  console.log('listGroupArray',listGroupArray)
  console.log('listGroupArray added',Math.round(listGroupArray.reduce(add,0) ));
})


function add(a,b) {
        return a +b;
    }
```

Comment: create a map with the key based on the div id update counts there

Comment: Not sure if I follow your logic.  Would you have an example to show?

Comment: @arcyqwerty provided a solid answer that reduces code.  I do not think this should be voted down.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could select which array using a conditional and then call push on it.

```
var array;
if (condition) {
  array = navArray;
} else {
  array = panelHeadingArray;
}
array.push(...);
```

or more concisely using the ternary operator

```
(condition ? navArray : panelHeadingArray).push(...)
```

Edit:

```
var enteredTime = 0;
var jumbotronArray = [];
var listGroupArray = [];

var mapping = {
  ".jumbotron": jumbotronArray,
  ".list-group": listGroupArray
};

Object.keys(mapping).forEach(function(selector) {
  $(selector).hover(function(evt) {
    enteredTime = new Date();
  }, function() {
    var ctime = new Date();
    var time = (ctime.getTime() - enteredTime.getTime())/1000;
    mapping[selector].push(time);
  });
}
```

Comment: My challenge is that this would be for about 20 divs.  I shortened this to make it easier to read.

Comment: I'm not sure where in your code you're trying to do this or what you're conditioning on to select the array.  If it's a conditional, you could use if/else or switch.  If it's index or string based, you could use an array/object to maintain references to the arrays.

Comment: This is what I am struggling to come up with.   I am updating my question to show a long way that I could do this with each element.  My goal is to get a better sense of being dry.

Comment: Still not quite sure which arrays you're trying to get values into and based on what conditions.  Can you provide an example including `array1 = []; array2 = [], array3 = [], ... if (something) array1.push(...); else if (something else) array2.push(...);...`?

Comment: I added the two functions in the update at the bottom.   They are both the same.  Ideally I could make those reusable.

Comment: Updated answer with example mapping.  If you don't need to reference `jumbotronArray` and `listGroupArray` the way you are now, you could also roll them right into the mapping (`{
  ".jumbotron": [],
  ".list-group": []
}`) and access them by their keys (`mapping['.jumbotron']` or `mapping['.list-group']`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90276/discussion-between-steve-k-and-arcyqwerty).